# Make a workflow chart based on picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I am assigned a task to build a workflow chart based on the given picture [workflow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdkvF.png)

I tried to search for different libraries, but does not know how to use anyone of them.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any JavaScript framework like Angular or React? If you are on native javascript, you can check out my favorite library for charting - [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)

Comment: Thank you. But they don't have the workflow sort of chart.

Comment: @Lambchop123 in that case you might want to try https://d3js.org/ It can draw basically anything you want with SVG.